# Linux Mint "slurm" appears on login screen

Tags: linux-mint, slurm

On my login screen recently the text `slurm` appeared above my login name. What can be its reason? How can it be removed?

I use [Linux Mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/) version 19.1 'Tessa' with its Cinnamon desktop environment.

`uname -mrs` shows

> Linux 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64

[slurm](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/slurm-client-emulator) is not installed on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when I removed the `slurm` package, the automatically created  user `slurm` was not removed. Removing this user solved the question.